# In Instead Of Trigger how to do original process

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, triggers

In this below code have created trigger for  Table X_test ,in trigger have inserted value in X_test1 but after this Inserted i want the original insert or update want to happen with out writing manual code.
example if i insert one new record then it will inserted only X_test1 but i want to insert X_test also with out another new insert statement in Trigger is possible?
  I know the "After" trigger will use for this but in Instead of trigger how can we achieve this?because in my scenario i need this ..Pls help me...

```
create table X_test(Id int,name varchar(100))

create table X_test1(Id int,name varchar(100))

Create trigger X_trigger on X_test
Instead of Insert,update
as
begin
 Insert into X_test1
 Select id,Name from Inserted

 End


 Insert into X_test values(1,'a')

 select * from X_test
 select * from X_test1
```

Comment: Why don't you want to write out another insert?  I can't imagine any scenario where you would need to avoid this, and I don't know any way it's possible.

Comment: Mr.Alleman just i want to know if any other possible is available and this table have near 100 columns so for update want to write long code like Update X_test1 set col1=Inserted.column1 ,col2=Inserted.col2.....so only..Thanks for your quick response..

Comment: Ok, so you don't need to avoid it, you just want to.  Unfortunately I am pretty sure it's not possible.  You can right-click your table and select "Script As>Insert To>Clipboard." and it will generate most of the insert code for you to paste into your trigger code.

Comment: Create trigger X_trigger on X_test
Instead of IF update(ColName)
as
begin 
--Our Quey
ENd 
Hi @TabAlleman some think like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

When you use insted of you have to put all the code for what you want to do in the trigger. Instead of means exactly that, it takes the actions specified instead of the normal insert/update/delete actions. WHy can't you use the code from waht ever is generating the insert? That should save you time.

Comment: Create trigger X_trigger on X_test Instead of IF update(ColName) as begin --Our Quey ENd Hi @TabAlleman some think like this possible? 
Shall we fire trigger if particular column is updated only is possible?

Comment: No, a trigger always fires on the statement it is set to fire on (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE).  You can't make that part of it depend on the columns affected.  Then once it has fired you can choose what to do depending on whether certain columns are updated.